# How to fix this error on logging into facebook using android?

Tags: android, facebook

I have integrated facebook with my app. But now when i click the facebook login button i get the following errors. It works fine on my system but gets the following error when i run it on another system.Please can anyone tell me how to fix this?

```
                 02-14 16:02:28.504: E/AndroidRuntime(1349): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                 02-14 16:02:28.504: E/AndroidRuntime(1349): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.smacon.task/com.smacon.task.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
                02-14 16:02:28.504: E/AndroidRuntime(1349):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
                02-14 16:02:28.504: E/AndroidRuntime(1349):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
                02-14 16:02:28.504: E/AndroidRuntime(1349):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
               02-14 16:02:28.504: E/AndroidRuntime(1349):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
               02-14 16:02:28.504: E/AndroidRuntime(1349):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
               02-14 16:02:28.504: E/AndroidRuntime(1349):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                   02-14 16:02:28.504: E/AndroidRuntime(1349):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
                 02-14 16:02:28.504: E/AndroidRuntime(1349):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                02-14 16:02:28.504: E/AndroidRuntime(1349):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                02-14 16:02:28.504: E/AndroidRuntime(1349):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
                 02-14 16:02:28.504: E/AndroidRuntime(1349):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
                 02-14 16:02:28.504: E/AndroidRuntime(1349):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                  02-14 16:02:28.504: E/AndroidRuntime(1349): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
                   02-14 16:02:28.504: E/AndroidRuntime(1349):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:698)
                    02-14 16:02:28.504: E/AndroidRuntime(1349):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:466)
                   02-14 16:02:28.504: E/AndroidRuntime(1349):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
                 02-14 16:02:28.504: E/AndroidRuntime(1349):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
                   02-14 16:02:28.504: E/AndroidRuntime(1349):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:270)
                    02-14 16:02:28.504: E/AndroidRuntime(1349):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1881)
                      02-14 16:02:28.504: E/AndroidRuntime(1349):   at com.smacon.task.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:46)
              02-14 16:02:28.504: E/AndroidRuntime(1349):   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
                    02-14 16:02:28.504: E/AndroidRuntime(1349):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
                     02-14 16:02:28.504: E/AndroidRuntime(1349):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
              02-14 16:02:28.504: E/AndroidRuntime(1349):   ... 11 more
            02-14 16:02:28.504: E/AndroidRuntime(1349): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout" on path: /data/app/com.smacon.task-2.apk
            02-14 16:02:28.504: E/AndroidRuntime(1349):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
            02-14 16:02:28.504: E/AndroidRuntime(1349):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
                02-14 16:02:28.504: E/AndroidRuntime(1349):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
            02-14 16:02:28.504: E/AndroidRuntime(1349):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:552)
                  02-14 16:02:28.504: E/AndroidRuntime(1349):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:687)
                02-14 16:02:28.504: E/AndroidRuntime(1349):     ... 20 more
                   02-14 16:02:34.544: E/com.facebook.LoginActivity(1368): Cannot call LoginActivity with a null calling package. This can occur if the launchMode of the caller is singleInstance.
```

Comment: what do you mean by system?!.. you mean android device or another eclipse?

Comment: I mean first i was working on one computer, then i tried to run it on another computer

Answer (score 0):

You are using your Android's SDK Support V4 file, you need to use the Facebook's SDK one, it's in the bin folder of the folder, replace it in both places.

Comment: I am using android's v4 bcoz i have a drawerlayout in the next activity. If i replace it with fb v4 it results in forceclose giving errors